# AWK won't edit file windows

Tags: windows, awk

I'm trying to get AWK to work, specifically the instructions from [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/replace-2nd-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-sed-or-awk-800171/). I've got a file containing

`John
Betty
Jack
Ron
Jack
Paul`

And am running `awk "/Jack/{c++;if(c==2){sub("Jack","Rob");c=0}}1" testawk.txt`

Which then simply returns the original list of 6 names, without Jack edited, nor is the actual file edited. Im running the command prompt in administrator mode in the correct path. Any idea?

Comment: use single quotes around your awk code: `awk '/Jack/{c++;if(c==2){sub("Jack","Rob");c=0}}1'`.

Comment: Then I get the error `awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression`

Comment: Try to invert the quotes (I don't have Windows to test it): `awk "/Jack/{c++;if(c==2){sub('Jack','Rob');c=0}}1"` or try to escape double quotes around Jack and Rob.

Comment: Same error, `awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression` pointing to the ' before the 2nd Jack.

Edit: Sleep deprivation makes me read bad, escaping the quotes worked. Cheers!

Comment: You need backslashes in front of the quote marks around Jack and Rob: sub(\"Jack\",\"Rob\").  I assume the names you show are in the file named testawk.txt?  The file testawk.txt will not be modified; output will be written to stdout, which you can redirect to a file if you like.

Comment: Yes, the backslashes worked for the quotation marks. I read it out as `>testawk2.txt` afterwards, so it'd save in that file.